# How to complete CONCAT if some of the values is missing - SQL?

Tags: sql, isnull

I'm very new in SQL and have to modify this existing code:

```
CONCAT(
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'series_title'), 
    ' : ',
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'episode_title')
  ) as complete_title,
```

My question is how to write if 'series_title' is missing?

I've put in this right before CONCAT, but it indicates that something is wrong/missing:

```
WHERE
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key IS NULL)
  THEN
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'episode_title') as complete_title,
  ELSE
```

OK, some completions:

I have this query in BigQuery, which is NoSQL(?).

The reason of the modification is that the `'series_title'` value, which we use to create the `complete_title` value, is missing for a part of our programs. So that I try to get pull out in these case is the `'episode_title'`solely as `complete_title`. Otherwise - if both exist - `'series_title'` and `'episode_title'` together gets as `complete_title`.

event_params is the parameters we have available like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6UVy.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What do you want to happen if thetitle is missing?

Comment: What data type is `event_params` and what does it contain exactly?  And which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'series_title')
```

Comment: do you mean instead of WHERE
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key IS NULL)? Before THEN?

Comment: @UEN . .  You can include this logic in the `WHEN` part of a `CASE` expression, but you have `WHERE` in your question.

Comment: Hm. I've tried both WHEN and WHERE, but it still doesn't work. 

WHEN
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'series_title')
THEN
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'episode_title') as complete_title,
ELSE
CONCAT(
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'series_title'), 
    ' : ',
    (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'episode_title')
  ) as complete_title,